# How to Append Columns to Dataframe in Loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

New here and would appreciate help with a recurring problem I've been having.

I am working with the below code trying to have "delta", "gain", "loss", "avg gain", "avg loss", "RS" and "RSI" appended as new columns using the following loop. When I run the loop, there are no error messages and I can run the RSI function, but no columns are appended to the df dataframe.  However, when I run the code line by line instead of selecting the whole loop block and running it that way, the dataframe populates with the columns. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I want the columns to populate when I run this code as a loop.

```
df = ohlcv.copy()
def RSI(DF,n):
    df = DF.copy()
    df['delta']=df['Adj Close'] - df['Adj Close'].shift(1)
    df['gain']=np.where(df['delta']>=0,df['delta'],0)
    df['loss']=np.where(df['delta']<0,abs(df['delta']),0)
    avg_gain = []
    avg_loss = []
    gain = df['gain'].tolist()
    loss = df['loss'].tolist()
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i < n:
            avg_gain.append(np.NaN)
            avg_loss.append(np.NaN)
        elif i == n:
            avg_gain.append(df['gain'].rolling(n).mean().tolist()[n])
            avg_loss.append(df['loss'].rolling(n).mean().tolist()[n])
        elif i > n:
            avg_gain.append(((n-1)*avg_gain[i-1] + gain[i])/n)
            avg_loss.append(((n-1)*avg_loss[i-1] + loss[i])/n)
    df['avg_gain']=np.array(avg_gain)
    df['avg_loss']=np.array(avg_loss)
    df['RS'] = df['avg_gain']/df['avg_loss']
    df['RSI'] = 100 - (100/(1+df['RS']))
    return df['RSI']
```

Sorry if this is a rookie question, but I have to start somewhere!

Comment: You are returning `return df['RSI']` which is just 1 column -- return `df` instead

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal Thank you - this helps in returning all of the columns when I run ''' return df ''', but they are still not added to the "df" dataframe when I run the loop. Do you know why this may be?